# Various sentence structures

Tags: standard-german

Is there a website or other resource that contains examples of the various types of structures of german sentences? Resources with a similar purpose are welcomed as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "types of structures"? Hauptsatz, Relativsatz, Fragesatz... or what categories?

Comment: Or do you mean sentences containing different types of constituents like subject, object, predicative, adverbial ...? Or are you talking about different performative functions like assertion, denial, request, appeal, confirmation, proposition, valuation, refusal ...?

Answer (score 3):

Is anything wrong with the sites you can find searching for `sentence structure German`?

> Resources with a similar purpose are welcomed as well.

If you want to analyze the structure of an arbitrary sentence, this site may be helpful:
https://pub.cl.uzh.ch/demo/parzu/
It uses the "[Stuttgart Tübingen Tagset](https://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/forschung/ressourcen/lexika/TagSets/stts-table.html)" to annotate the parts of speech.